# Using WPF and Caliburn Micro: Based on a ViewModel's constructor's parameter, i would like to start a view with a specific parameter

Tags: c#, view, arguments, viewmodel, caliburn.micro

I have a viewModel and a corresponding view using the Caliburn.Micro architecture. (using C# and WPF), that works and shows just fine, but I want to pass a parameter to the View's constructor.  How can i do this?

(put another way: How can i pass a parameter given to the ViewModel's constructor to the View's constructor?)

thanks!

Comment: Why does your `View` needs it when there is a `ViewModel`. View should be as dumb as possible except display logic of course. Why can't the value passed in binding instead of constructor?

Comment: Well I want the view to initialize one of its controls with a parameter that is known by the viewmodel.  I'm new to caliburn.micro etc, or how else do I "get" this value.  My view just contains one WPF usercontrol.  This userControl contains a listbox that i want initialized to highlight a specific item in the list.

Comment: Forget about caliburn for a moment, just to understand your case, Did you try usual data binding? Or is there anything that prevent you from doing that? If that is the case, mention that in the question so that we can understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you wouldn't do this for a number of reasons.

1. Without a parameter less constructor the visual designer will usually fail.
2. View creation is usually done by the framework and doesn't involve any container.

Usually data is passed from the view model to the view through bindings. In your cased you would expose a property on the view model and bind it like below.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Not that none of this is related to Caliburn.Micro but how you would normally approach a problem like this in xaml based framework.

There are built in conventions in Caliburn.Micro for these circumstances. The above could be replaced with.

```
<ListBox x:Name="Products" />
```